# Get record index column in linq select

Tags: linq, select, indexing

I need to get index in my select statement.

My code:

```
IQueryable grpdRows;
dtInput = ds.Tables[0];
grpdRows = dtInput
    .Select("", "partno")
    .AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy("new (iif(it[\"partno\"] == null, \"\", it[\"partno\"]) as GrpKey1)","it")
    .Select("new (it.Key.GrpKey1 as GrpKey1, it.Count() as TotalCount")");
```

how to get index in select statement example:

```
.Select("new (it.Key.GrpKey1 as GrpKey1, it.Count() as TotalCount, **it.Index**")");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is possible via Dynamic Linq, but as workaround you can try something like this:

```
IQueryable grpdRows;
dtInput = ds.Tables[0];
grpdRows = dtInput
    .Select("", "partno")
    .AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy("new (iif(it[\"partno\"] == null, \"\", it[\"partno\"]) as GrpKey1)","it")
    .Select("new (it.Key.GrpKey1 as GrpKey1, it.Count() as TotalCount)");

var res = (from dynamic row in grpdRows
          select row).Select((row,index)=>new {row.GrpKey1, row.TotalCount, Index=i});
```